# Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' to 'SwipeCellKit.SwipeTableViewCell'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to use a pod called `SwipeCellKit` in my project, where this pod add a class called SwipeTableViewCell. What I have done so far is:

- Create a view controller to the storyboard.
- Create a `UIViewController` class.
- Import `SwipeCellKit` to the Swift file.
- Assign view controller to the class.
- Add table view to the view controller.
- Connect delegate and data source from table view to the view controller.
- Add prototype cell to the table view, and named it "cell" for its reusable identifier.
- **Change the cell class into SwipeTableViewCell.**
- Add table view delegate to the view controller.
- Add `numberOfRows` and `cellForRow` function to my UIViewController class.

This is the implementation of the `cellForRow`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! SwipeTableViewCell;
    return cell;
}
```

But I got error on the `let cell = ...`, saying:

> Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' to 'SwipeCellKit.SwipeTableViewCell'

Why? And how to fix this? I think I have arranged everything as it should be. Did I miss something?

Comment: While importing SwipeCellKit, have you checked for the target membership?

Comment: Unrelated but this is Swift: No trailing semicolons!

Comment: can you attach a demo

Comment: try clean and restarting the Xcode

Comment: I have selected the working answer for me. It's weird that I need to subclass the cell further in order to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your own Cell class as subclass of `SwipeTableViewCell` then you need to implement `SwipeTableViewCellDelegate` protocol in your ViewController

**and for this line**

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! SwipeTableViewCell
```

you should use your class name which is a `SwipeTableViewCell` subclass

**example**

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! MySwipeableCell
cell.delegate = self
```

Comment: It works!!!!!!!!! This is a very weird solution, but it works!!!!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

What solved the problem for me:

In **Main.Storyboard** (or where you have your views), make sure that everywhere you want to use the reusable "cell", in the Identity Inspector on the right pane, you have the following:

- Class is set to **SwipeTableViewCell**
- Module is set to **SwipeCellKit**.

Comment: **This** is the correct solution actually. Thanks man!

Comment: This worked, thanks

Comment: Also worked for me fam! The Lord Always Delivers! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I created the following example

```
import UIKit
import SwipeCellKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! SwipeTableViewCell
        return cell
    }

}


class SwipeTableViewCellSubClass: SwipeTableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

}
```

set the class for your view to be SwipeTableViewCellSubClass.

this should work perfectly for you. good luck

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In your main storyboard,
Select Prototype cell and change class to `SwipeTableViewCell`
Change module to `SwipeCellKit`

Answer (score 0):

To fix without creating a custom class, simply click your prototype cell:

[image: Select the prototype cell]

Then from the "identity inspector" select "SwipeTableViewCell" as the class, from the "SwipeCellKit" module, like so:

[image: Add the class and module]

Answer (score 0):

this error was casue because you set cell value inside viewDidLoad() ftn().